# Testing for statistical significance in survey results for different countries

Tags: anova, statistical-significance, survey

I have just run the same survey on websites in different countries and I want to be able to tell whether there are significant differences between countries.

For example if 20% of Germans donate to charity, 30% of British and 40% of Dutch, can you confidently say that the Dutch donate twice as much to charity as the Germans?

Comment: No, you can  not say that Dutch donate to charity twice as much. As I understand, your "donors" are poorly defined (there is no difference if I give 1 euro or 1 000 euro). Have you some other numbers instead of percents? For example the detailed values of sums donated?

Comment: There's nothing stupid about the question. But you ought to sit back and think hard about the non-technical issues before getting into the numbers: do you really think you can generalize about the Germans, British, Dutch, or whoever, based on what a few people say on a *Web survey*?  This seems rather unlikely, but if you can find a way to support this expectation, then it would make sense to look at the numbers (at which point you should heed @Ladislav's advice).

Comment: Sorry, that was just an example to make it simpler, the actual questions are more like "Have you donated to [charity name]" and "How strongly do you feel about the following causes" [on a Likert scale]. I was just wondering how to analyse whether there are significant differences between the countries' responses, in order to inform the charity's fundraising and content strategies in those countries.

Comment: That's actually a more difficult question than I originally thought. If there were only two countries, I would use a z-test (see http://www.answersresearch.com/proportions.php). But with several proportions, I would be inclined to use a chi-square test (see http://www.answersresearch.com/proportions.php). However, normally with a chi-square test, someone is asked to choose which of three options they prefer (or something like that), which your data are clearly different. However, I still think a chi2 would be appropriate.

Comment: To follow on whuber's point - you may like to think through these issues in particular: that [web users are not a random sample of the populations from which they arise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_bias) and that [people who self-select answering your survey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-selection) are not a random sample of people on the web. Given that, how would you reach probabilistic conclusions at all, and how would they generalize to your population of interest?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I see that it's not the best sampling method - but I'm working for a charity which doesn't have a massive budget so the web survey was the best way to do some quick and dirty research into their country audiences and get some idea of whether there are differences. They asked me about the statistical significance and I didn't know how to answer... I will look up the chi-squared test but remind them about the sampling bias. Thanks.